# CASE expression returns wrong values during percentage calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently working on a supermarket database design where I have to have retrieve the price of the product after discount.

There are 2 types of discount: Direct Discount, Quantity Based Discount. The product will either have percentage discount (eg: 10% off) or amount/cash discount (eg: $5 off)

Currently, my code only works for quantity based discount but not the direct discount (percentage discount) where it will return a wrong value.

```
select id, product_name, unitPrice,Product.discount_cd,
discount_percentange as 'Discount Percentage' , 
discount_amount as 'Discount Amount',
Promotion_Type.quantity,
case when Product.discount_cd NOT LIKE '%DD' AND discount_percentange IS NOT NULL 
    THEN (unitPrice*ISNULL(discount_percentange,1))*ISNULL(quantity,1)
 when (Promotion_Type.discount_cd NOT LIKE '%QB' AND Promotion_Type.discount_percentange IS NOT NULL)
    THEN (unitPrice-(unitPrice*discount_percentange))
ELSE (unitPrice*ISNULL(quantity,1))-(unitPrice*ISNULL(discount_percentange,0))-(ISNULL(discount_amount,0))
END AS reduce
from Product
LEFT JOIN Promotion_Type ON Product.discount_cd=Promotion_Type.discount_cd
```

Based on the picture attached, reduced price for product P001 and P005 is wrong.
Can I know where is the error? The screenshot of the database table output
[database product table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BV4b.png)

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code and data as text, not images.

Comment: @Nick I only upload my table screenshot, i think i did include that code as text. Sorry for that.

Comment: If you also post your table data as text, people can use it to generate a test case which will make it a lot easier to find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see multiple issues with your `CASE` statement.

First, I think you are misusing the `%` wildcard. It represents any number of any characters at the place it is located. For example, `'%DD'` means anything as long as the last two characters are 'DD'. Adding the `NOT` just flips it. Therefore, `Product.discount_cd NOT LIKE '%DD'` will evaluate true as long as the `Product.discount_cd` does not end in `'DD'`, which is all of the codes. When you add in the `AND discount_percentage IS NOT NULL`, the result is, any record that has a `discount_percentage` will return with the first `THEN` statement. This includes P001 and P005.

Second, I think you are misusing the `ISNULL()` function. It's unnecessary to use it on `discount_percentage`as you have `IS NOT NULL` as a criterion. Also, if `quantity` refers to the product quantity, I do not think you should return a 1 when `quantity` is null.

Presuming that "DD" stands for "Direct Discount", I don't understand why you have records with a "DD" code and no `discount_percentage`. That being said, I think the below revised `CASE` statement will meet your needs.

```
CASE
    WHEN
        Product.discount_cd LIKE 'DD%' --Any code beginning with 'DD'
        AND discount_percentage IS NOT NULL --Must have discount percentage
        THEN (unitPrice * ISNULL(quantity,0)) - (unitPrice * ISNULL(quantity,0) * discount_percentage)
    WHEN
        Promotion_Type.discount_cd LIKE 'QB%' --Any code beginning with 'QB'
        AND discount_amount IS NOT NULL --Must have discount amount
        THEN unitPrice * ISNULL(quantity,0) - discount_amount
    ELSE 0 --No valid discount
END AS reduce
```

Comment: yes! I think the biggest issue of it is because of the `%` wildcard! It shows the correct value now! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Check this first condition,

```
case when Product.discount_cd NOT LIKE '%DD' AND discount_percentange IS NOT NULL 
    THEN (unitPrice*ISNULL(discount_percentange,1))*ISNULL(quantity,1)
```

The unit discount amount  should be deducted from unitPrice.

```
case when Product.discount_cd NOT LIKE '%DD' AND discount_percentange IS NOT NULL 
 THEN (unitPrice-(unitPrice*ISNULL(discount_percentange,1)))*ISNULL(quantity,1)
```